# How to fix this issue about plugin incompatibility?

Tags: intellij-idea, error-handling

In Intellij IDE, the error is showing like this
`- Plugin error : Plugin "Python Community Edition" is incompitable (since build 203.5981 > IC - 202.8194.7`

Comment: Can you show the error?

Answer (score -1):

[Install the plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html#install_plugin_from_repo), compatible with your current IDE version in Settings | Plugins page.

[image]